# DLNA server that writes popular rating and play counts to ID3?

Tags: dlna, id3

I like Kodi, but it has no feature to write play counts and ratings to ID3 frames into files. So I'm looking for some streaming server which is able to write that. For connectivity reasons the server should support DLNA.

The tags in the files are very necessary for me.

Ampache is nice, but it seems not to write ratings and play counts to files, if ID3 writing is enabled.

Any advices?